# youtube default image,video without api

Tags: javascript, html, youtube

I'm developing a site in which i will show youtube videos to the user,

Steps:

1)i'll upload video urls to Database (manually i'll enter url into database.)

2)using that url i want to show a default image in my site

3)if user clicks on that url video will play.

is it possible to do this without youtube api ?

Comment: Sure, there are alternatives to Youtube. Vimeo, rolling your own flash player,...; using Youtube without its API might be problematic.

Comment: thanks for reply, please give some sample code ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YouTube video has 4 images by default provided by youtube

```
http://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/0.jpg
http://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/1.jpg
http://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/2.jpg
http://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/3.jpg
```

Display those images and when user clicks on it show the video

Answer (score 0):

w3schools have a tutorial section on how to do this with basic HTML; javascript isn't required:

> ```
> <video width="320" height="240" controls>
>   <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
>   <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
>   <source src="movie.webm" type="video/webm">
>   <object data="movie.mp4" width="320" height="240">
>     <embed src="movie.swf" width="320" height="240">
>   </object> 
> </video>
> ```

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_videos.asp

Comment: W3Schools are not W3C, they are not affiliated with W3C, and they are not nearly as good as the World Wide Web Consortium either.

Comment: Note that this is a link-only answer (not welcome here). You should extract the interesting part(s) here.